# Strange behavior when overriding properties for a spring-boot application deployed as a WAR in a Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring-boot application which I need to deploy as a WAR in a tomcat.
I also need to define / override some properties so that this application can work in this environment.

I was able to do so by creating a file `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/backend.xml` with the same name as my WAR file. Here the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true" crossContext="true" override="true" path="/back" docBase="/home/myAppUser/webapps/backend.war">
    <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="prod" type="java.lang.String" />
    <Environment name="application.attachmentBaseDirectory" value="/home/myAppUser/attachments" type="java.lang.String" />
    <Environment name="application.redirect-url" value="http://myapp.mycompany.org/frontend" type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
```

All environment variables but `application.attachmentBaseDirectory` work.
The application continue to use the one defined for my development environment on Windows: `C:\tmp\attachments`…

Yet, if I create a file `/home/myAppUser/application.yml` or `/home/myAppUser/config/application.yml`, the value is correctly overridden…

```
application:
  attachmentBaseDirectory: /home/myAppUser/attachments
```

But if I define all the values inside this file in place of `backend.xml`, none of them but `application.attachmentBaseDirectory` work…

So here is my questions:

1. Why the overriding in `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/backend.xml` isn't working for this value, but work for others?
2. How come the WAR is able to find the `application.yml` when running inside of a tomcat?
3. Why the `application.attachmentBaseDirectory` property does work from the `application.yml` file, but others don't?

**Some more information:**

Here the content on my `ApplicationProperties.java`.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class ApplicationProperties {

    /**
     * The URL to which we should redirect the user once he is logged in the application.
     */
    private String redirectUrl;

    /**
     * The base directory in which we should put the attachments.
     */
    private String attachmentBaseDirectory;

}
```

This bean is then use in a `@Controller` for the `redirectUrl` to redirect to another web page, and in a `@Service` for the `attachmentBaseDirectory` to save files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why the property `application.attachmentBaseDirectory` didn't work when set in `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/backend.xml`:

It is because it was named `application.attachmentBaseDirectory` ([camel case](https://wprock.fr/blog/conventions-nommage-programmation/)) and not `application.attachment-base-directory` ([kebab case](https://wprock.fr/blog/conventions-nommage-programmation/)).

[Spring-boot allow relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding), but it seems that to be used through tomcat context, the [kebab case](https://wprock.fr/blog/conventions-nommage-programmation/) way is the one to go.

---

Yet to solve:

- How come the WAR is able to find the `application.yml` in the `home` directory when running inside tomcat?

  - *I am suspecting that it is because I launch the tomcat from my home directory.*
- Why the `application.attachmentBaseDirectory` works from `application.yml` but others properties don't?